# Why is ASP.net WebApi escaping dates in JSON output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on a project where WebApi escaping dates. For example.

```
{"Date":"11\/05\/2016"}
```

and it must be this

```
{"Date":"11/05/2016"}
```

The model.

```
public class XModel
{
        public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

The controller.

```
public class DatesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/dates/{take:int?}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(XModel))]
    public XModel GetDates(int take = 0)
    {
        return new XModel()
        {
            Date = "11/05/2016"
        };
    }
}
```

It looks like the project is escaping every slash ("/") in the JSON response. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Comment: Why returning a string when you could return a `DateTime`? + A class with only one property is not really useful ...

Comment: You should return a DateTime or a DateTimeOffset. Make sure your serializer is properly configured (should be out of the box with a new web api project). You want your datetime to be serialized in ISO8601 format (again most serializers like json.net do this by default). Using a string in your model is bad practice and a great way to introduce defects in your code, dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're already using a json serializer for you web api, so try this way:

```
public class DatesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/dates/{take:int?}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDates(int take = 0)
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            Date = "11/05/2016"
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!